# Deciding how to model this data in django

Tags: django, models

Imagine it is for translating vocabulary to another language. I'm only dealing with a limited number of words (~2000).

Language1 and Language2 (which will have a different ~2000 words), each might have multiple words equivalents from the other language which may or may not be on the list of ~2000 words of the other language.

Using a many-to-many relationship initially appealed to me, but I can't quite see through the mist to see what would work best.

My other thought was just making a json dump for each word. Something like....

```
{1: {'Lang1': [word1, word2], 'Lang2': [word1, word2]}}
```

but I am not sure if that is too smart to manage everything like that, it would be cumbersome to do from the admin section (because I think I would be editing a long line of text that is a json object) and it doesn't take advantage of much.

Maybe there is another way that I havent thought of?

Given my scenario, how would you go about defining this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Language(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Word(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   language = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name='language_words')
   #...

class Translation(models.Model):
   word = models.ForeignKey(Word, related_name='word_translations')
   translation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   from_language = models.ForeignKey(Language, related_name='language_translations')
   in_language = models.CharField(max_length=100)


# stage performances
english_language = Language(name='english')
english_language.save()

word = english_language.language_words.create(name='Flower')
german_translation = word.word_translations.create(translation='Blumen',
                                                   from_language=english_language,
                                                   in_language='German')



word # 'Flower'
german_translation # 'Blumen'
```

might not be optimal yet, i am in the train right now, but this can be a good way to start hopefully.

then if you register these models into admin, you can easily manage (add/delete) translations..

Comment: I think this might be what I am looking for. I'll play around with it a little bit and let you know. Thanks for the answer